# Combining <pre> and <p> tags

Tags: html

I have a long text. `<pre>` tag is good to see this text with line breaks in browser as I see it in notepad. So, i don't need to add `<br>` for each line breaks. But in this case, the problem is that horizontal scroll bar appears. `<p>` tag solves this problem. But `<p>` tag is not sensitive to line breaks in text.
I tried to combine `<pre>` and `<p>` tags. For example `<p><pre>long text</pre></p>`. But I learned that it can't. In summary, I want to see my long text in browser as in notepad with line breaks and  word wrap enabled. How can i do it? Excuse me for my bad English.

Comment: Can you share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem? How should the result look like? Automated line breaks are not usual in `<pre>`

Comment: There is not automated line breaks. I add the line breaks myself in my text editor like notepad. So, I want to see line breaks in browser.  If I don't add `<pre>`, line breaks don't appear in browser. So i use `<pre>`. But also I want not to see horizontal scroll bar in browser. `<pre>` tag does'nt solve horizontal scroll bar problem although `<p>` solves.